# Does the sequence $\tan(n\pi+(\pi/4)\cos(n\pi)$ when n goes to $\infty$ diverges or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I thought that every $\tan$ sequence will diverge, since  as n goes to $\infty$ the sequence will oscilliates ranging from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Is my logic right or not?

If it does right, how to prove this osciliation?
Thank you.

Comment: It seems you're missing a parenthesis in the equation in the title?

Comment: Wrong, because for example $\tan(n\pi)=0$ for all $n$, and thus converges. However your sequence does not; it oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. Use the fact that $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic and odd, and $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$ to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the sequence should be $$\tan(n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4})\cos(n\pi).$$

Notice at $n=0$, we have,
$$\tan(0\pi + \frac{\pi}{4})\cos(0\pi) = \tan(\frac{\pi}{4})\cos(0) = (1)(1) = 1.$$

Since all the trig functions are periodic in $2\pi$ (where $\tan(n)$ a smaller fundamental period of $\pi$), we see that we also get the same result for $n = 2, 4, 6, \dots$.

Now consider $n=1$, we have,
$$\tan(1\pi + \frac{\pi}{4})\cos(1\pi) = \tan(\frac{5\pi}{4})\cos(\pi) = (1)(-1) = -1.$$

For the same reason as before, we get the same result when $n = 3, 5, 7, \dots$.

Thus, we see that our sequence ends up being $(1, -1, 1, -1, \dots)$ which diverges.

Comment: $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic, though.

Comment: The fundamental period of $\tan$ is $\pi$ but it is still also $2\pi$ periodic (and $n\pi$ periodic for any integer $n$).

Comment: Obviously, but it's better to make it clear to a student who has some confusion on the matter - and the OP seems to have it.

Comment: Good point. I edited the answer to reflect that.